# How to add a separate Analytics for each website page in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, google-analytics, analytics

We have a WordPress installation that has locations as separate pages.

For example: mysite.com/colorado and mysite.com/alabama

We need separate google analytics for each of these as well as 1 for all of mysite.com.

Is there a way to do this with a WordPress plugin(s) or will we need to hand code some things?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, Google Analytics lets you view your analytics in a breakdown like that. That said, if you **do** need individual scripts, it would be relatively easy to program in. There may be some plugins that do this, but I'm not aware of any in particular, though a cursory glance showed plugins like [Header and Footer Scripts](https://wordpress.org/plugins/header-and-footer-scripts/) that allow you to add scripts on a page by page basis.

Some themes also allow you to add SEO/Script settings per page/post. If that's the case, you can just open up each page and dump each script tag in the "header scripts" or similar section, and call it good. (Genesis is an example of a theme that does this).

If not, programming this would be relatively straight forward. I'd do it something like this:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'display_analytics_by_page', 1 );
function display_analytics_by_page(){
    // Default Script Code with individual UA codes replaced
    $script = '<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
        <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=[UA-CODE]"></script>
        <script>
          window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
          function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
          gtag(\'js\', new Date());

          gtag(\'config\', \'[UA-CODE]\');
        </script>';

    // Array of UA codes by state
    $codes = array(
        'Alabama' => 'UA-123456789-1',
        'Oregon'  => 'UA-987654542-3',
        'Vermont' => 'UA-000000000-0'
    );

    // Get title of this page
    $title = get_the_title();

    // If this page title exists in the codes array, swap placeholder and echo it.
    if( isset($codes[$title]) ){
        echo str_replace( '[UA-CODE]', $codes[$title], $script );           
    }
}
```

I commented along the way, but the gist is to put in the "default" script, but pull out the UA code. This will only work if you need the same  exact script code in each one, otherwise you'll have to add each script to the `$codes` array instead.

Then create an array of the UA Codes (or full scripts if needed), keyed by the page title.

Then check the page title, and if that exists, pull that code in and echo it. This is run on the `wp_head` hook, so you just need to put this code in your `functions.php` (or similar) file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm going to let the question simmer a bit longer and will probably go with your answer. Much appreciated!

Comment: A cursory looks shows there's plugins like [Header and Footer Scripts](https://wordpress.org/plugins/header-and-footer-scripts/) that would allow you to add scripts on individual pages. That would be an easier, albeit less extensible way of doing it.

Comment: Right! I have looked at some of these, as well as the thought of creating templates for each location as well.....I am liking the code way for adding properties, however since this will be a site that lets its owner do things it may just be a preference....

Comment: It would be easy enough to add user-specific fields instead too. Create a `usermeta` field called "UA Code", and get the page-author's code if they have it saved, instead of using the `$codes` array. Plenty of ways to make it extensible :)

Comment: We ended up having a single account that will work. But I chose your answer as I said I would since it was a viable solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go easy with no-coding, then go with a plugin. Jump to **Plugins > Add New** and **Search** for **Google Analytics** in the search box. Install the plugin named **Google Analytics for WordPress (Formerly GADWP)**. Activate and connect the plugin with your Google Analytics property. When all is done, you will see a [new tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QELj4.png) beside your post's title. See a screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QELj4.png).

And if you want the net analytics for the whole web site then head to your admin dashboard. A new widget will appear there with the analytics.

Documentation for the plugin can be found [here](https://exactmetrics.com/category/documentation/).

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'm curious why you need a separate GA account for all the locations? Common practice in this scenario would be:

- Use 1 account
- Create 1 GA view for the entire domain
- Create +1 view for each location by filtering traffic based on the URL

If the different accounts are related to limiting user access, know that you can grant user access based on each property view.

Comment: I'll check with the client.....currently they use a proprietary CMS. And each has their own dashboard with their stats.

We don't want Colorado seeing Alabama etc. But I think I can limit this in Wordpress to the page(s) they can edit they can click the column for that page.

Comment: Confirmed. One account will be fine to add each location to the main account. They currently have separate accounts and thought to make that a requirement. So We should be good to go! Thanks for the input.